# Can't get rid of splash screen in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios, ios4, splash-screen

I removed the Default.png image from the resources folder yet the picture is still there, as a splash screen upon start up of the app.

Comment: I was thinking clean all targets but do both boxes have to be ticked or not, or...?

Comment: Ok so it seems that I have finally got rid of it by cleaning all targets, deleting in simulator, and then build and run in xcode again

Comment: Add this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so it seems that I have finally got rid of it by cleaning all targets, deleting in simulator, and then build and run in xcode again

Comment: The problem is that the default way in which Xcode loads your app onto the device is that it just copies files over, it does NOT remove existing files. This can cause lots of problems if you, for example, move a NIB file from the top level directory to a subdirectory. The old NIB file won't be removed and will likely still be loaded by default.